# C# XML - can't read XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to read a whole xml file loaded in doc. And I'm trying to iterate through each node and have a comparison with the textboxes to see if their account exists

Sorry for not being to in depth, its my first post, I hope these image will help: just to note, the source code worked perfectly in a console application, however doesn't in a Windows form application but when I click login button nothing seems to happen, but works in console application but not this, any ideas?

Source code:

[image: Source code]

Xml I'm reading from:

[image: Xml file]

Source code not in an image:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string User = txtUserName.Text;
        string pass = txtPassword.Text;

        XmlDocument Doc = new XmlDocument();
        Doc.Load("login.xml");

        //iterating through each node to use for comparison for the textboxes

        foreach (XmlNode CurrentNode in Doc.SelectNodes("accounts/user"))
        {
            string username = CurrentNode.SelectSingleNode("username").InnerText;
            string password = CurrentNode.SelectSingleNode("password").InnerText;



            if (txtUserName.Text == username && txtPassword.Text == password)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Account exists");
            }
            else 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("does not exist");
            }


        }
```

Comment: please do not post your source code as screenshot

Comment: Please post the code in the question.  Also, when you step through this in a debugger, where/how specifically does it fail?  (Your logic also seems a little bit broken.  If there are 100 entries in the file, do you *really* want 99 message boxes telling you that each entry didn't match?)

Comment: And it probably is that you have to change "accounts/user" to "players/user" but that is just and educated guess.

Comment: oh sorry, my bad, first time , im completely new to programming, but in my console application, it just outputs one message, if its valid. Sorry  i dont make any sense again.

Comment: i've done like u said and how now put it into code window instead of image

Comment: Thanks guys i fixed it thanks to ur help, sorry about my noobiness

Answer (score 0):

Lets do a small refactoring and introduce special function, that checks username/password

```
static bool CheckLogin(string path, string username, string pwd)
{
return XDocument.Load(path).Root
.Elements("user")
.Any(x=>x.Element("username").Value==username && x.Element("password").Value==pwd);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of providing in the code as login.xml, try providing the complete path where the xml is present.

Comment: thanks for the input, does not seem to work, im pulling my hair out of this,

Comment: As @Thomas mentioned the code should be players/user in the code

Comment: Thanks guys i fixed it thanks to ur help, sorry about my noobiness